# Image Editors with Layering Capability

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I am a keen photographer and have tried many FOSS image editors, finally settling on DigiKam/Showfoto with Kipi plugins.  I occasionally use Dark table also as I think it is a promising project.

There is one piece of functionality that any of these applications have that I miss from my Photoshop/lightroon days.  That is the ability to create image layers.  I am aware GIMP has this capability (and I use it reluctantly) but unfortunately I am not a big fan, so my question is simple.

**Other than GIMP, is anyone aware of FOSS image editors with layering capability?**

To be concise I am not asking about creating image montages or collations this is simply about creating layers from a single image (background replacement etc)

Other editors I have tried, Raw Therapee, Bibble Pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A program I have used is `Pinta`, which is a GTK implementation of Paint.net version 3;  it may thus look familiar to people who have used that other program. It has good support for image layers, although obviously nothing like as much as the `GIMP`. Make sure that you have the layer toolbox opened and visible on screen (see the right hand side of the screenshot); this can be enabled from `View > Tool Windows > Layers`. At the top of the menu bar is the layers tab, which has options for adding new layers, merging layers, altering the various transparency levels and more.

It is possible to do much in `Pinta` with layers as [this  tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/editing-images-with-pinta) demonstrates, and this is an excellent introduction to the programs's layer functionality. It is apparent that backgrounds and objects can be removed, changed, or made transparent. Other photos or objects can be superimposed upon existing pictures and then the result merged and saved as a new file. The `GIMP` has more options and functionality, but Pinta will probably suffice for relatively straightforward image editing with layers.

As a note, the version of `Pinta` in the repositories is version 1.1; the latest available version is 1.3, which has some improvements in layer handling and one or two bug fixes. In particular, layers can now be rotated and zoomed, which may be useful in some projects. The latest version is available as a `PPA`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pinta-maintainers/pinta-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pinta
```

Instead of the `PPA`, you can of course build the very latest version from source using the stable source code or the GIT development code; see [here](http://pinta-project.com/pinta/HowTo.Installing-Pinta.ashx) for more instructions.

Note: I have just successfully compiled the Git version, and the version from there is labelled as 1.4, and there are a few other minor bugfixes and changes. **However** considering this [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pinta/+bug/999571) regarding saving images, which may affect some users of the Git development version, it is probably best to use the stable PPA version.

[image]

Comment: +1 Screenshot looks comprehensive (and familiar)  I have seen the name before but have never tried it.  I will look at the tutorial later today as well as have a play. Thanks

Comment: I'll add a note to my post about version 1.3, which has even better support for layers; the version in the repositories is version 1.1.